# Looking for land value data for anywhere in North America especially for Florida

Tags: data, routing, road, land-cover, cost-path

I am researching on road alignment optimization. The research goal is to find least cost road alignment between two given points, considering highway codes. One of major costs which I need to consider, is right-of-way cost. To present my methodology in a case study, I need actual land value data or estimated land value or average land value for different land categories. Data for Florida have higher priority than anywhere else, since I have other needed data for my research for Florida. 
Any recommendations?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it has land value data among other things for Florida:
https://www.fgdl.org/metadataexplorer/full_metadata.jsp?docId=%7BBF1746D0-6DA2-4A9F-9803-72D30CA22D90%7D&loggedIn=false

Comment: Nice catch Mathwiz!  That is exactly what the OP needs for Florida.  Not sure why you got a downvote, but I'm giving you an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

Land value (at the parcel level) is typically available from each county's Assessor office.  Most of these offices have web sites that allow you to download their parcel data (including assessed value) as a GIS layer.

In my experience there is little, if any, attribute schema consistency among counties; individual counties designed their digital parcel layers on their own, without coordinating their GIS layer design with adjoining counties. Accordingly, if you need data for a geographic area that spans multiple counties you'll probably have to massage each county's attribute table so that you can merge them into one unified, project-wide layer with a consistent schema.  Doable, but the effort becomes increasingly tedious as the number of counties in your project area increases.

Unified, statewide parcel layers *may*  be available.  For example, a Washington State GIS coordinating group put together a statewide parcel layer about 15 years ago.  Although the layer can still be accessed today, I believe that funding for the layer dried up, and as a result the layer is out of date.  But check around at the state GIS level - maybe your projct area has such a unified parcel layer.